# Using mutator in Laravel to populate column

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column in my booking model which stores datetime as `reservation_datetime`, however in my forms I have split this into two separate fields (date & time html5 inputs).

I have created a setter mutator to store date derived from the two inputs, however nothing is saved into the `reservation_datetime` column when the record is inserted.

**This is my mutator**

```
public function setReservationDatetimeAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->attributes['reservation_datetime'] = $this->date . " " . $this->time;
}
```

I've noticed that if I put pseudo inputs into my `$fillable` array (`reservation_datetime` is already present) then I am able to set the mutator to the correct value but this causes other issues where the ORM is trying to save `date` and `time` columns which obviously doesn't exist causing an error on save.

Comment: Mutators are the wrong tool for this. Set `reservation_datetime` manually in your controller.

Comment: Could you explain why this isnt the right function to use? My understanding is this is exactly what the mutator is used to do.

Comment: Mutators are to be used to other way around. If your form has a single field that you want to split in two, or simply mutate the value of a single attribute. Combining two attributes into one is simply not what mutators are about.

Comment: Please convert into answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutators are the wrong tool for this. Set `reservation_datetime` manually in your controller.

Mutators are meant to be used the other way around. For example if your form has a single field that you want to split in two, or to simply mutate the value of a single attribute.

Combining two attributes into one is simply not what mutators are about.